# PHPStorm Debug CLI to HTTP Request

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to debug a Laravel artisan command, executed via CLI, which in turn calls an external endpoint (via Guzzle).
Both the original app and the external endpoint are available locally, open in PHPStorm as two separate projects.

I'm able to debug the CLI command by running this command in terminal:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_port=9000 remote_host=127.0.0.1 remote_connect_back=0"
```

(or for windows):

```
set XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_port=9000 remote_host=127.0.0.1 remote_connect_back=0"
```

As illustrated on [PHPStorm docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Simultaneous+debugging+sessions+with+PhpStorm), you can execute an external script by passing a debug query string:

```
$debuggingQuerystring = '';
if (isset($_GET['XDEBUG_SESSION_START'])) { // xdebug
    $debuggingQuerystring = 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START=' . $_GET['XDEBUG_SESSION_START'];
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'])) { // xdebug (cookie)
    $debuggingQuerystring = 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM';
}
if (isset($_GET['start_debug'])) { // zend debugger
    $debuggingQuerystring = 'start_debug=' . $_GET['start_debug'];
}

$personJson = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:778/backend.php?' . $debuggingQuerystring);
```

The current problem that when executed via CLI, the $debugQueryString is empty. What do we pass along and how to the external url which will allow debugging on the second project?

```
$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client($this->webhook_url);
$response = $client->post('', [], $this->params)->send();

$code = $response->getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Why not **1)** `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your `php.ini`. NOTE that it will attempt to debug every single request processed by PHP interpreter that uses that php.ini (regardless of xdebug cookie/parameter). **2)** Place `xdebug_break();` in actual PHP code (programmatic breakpoint)...

Comment: P.S. Since it would be a secondary request .. you will need to increase the number of simultaneous debug connection in IDE (by default it's just 1)

Comment: I wanted to try and do it without auto_start as I can see that getting very annoying.

Comment: Yep, saw that - PHPStorm docs are awesome.

Comment: p.s. the new PHPStorm 9 with with JDK 1.8 is blazing fast!

Comment: Didn't know about xdebug_break(); thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

This was easier than I thought.

```
$debuggingQuerystring = '';
    if (isset($_GET['XDEBUG_SESSION_START'])) { // xdebug
        $debuggingQuerystring = 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START=' . $_GET['XDEBUG_SESSION_START'];
    }
    if (isset($_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'])) { // xdebug (cookie)
        $debuggingQuerystring = 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM';
    }
    if (isset($_GET['start_debug'])) { // zend debugger
        $debuggingQuerystring = 'start_debug=' . $_GET['start_debug'];
    }

    if(empty($debuggingQuerystring))
    {
        $debuggingQuerystring = 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM';
    }

    $this->debugString = $debuggingQuerystring;
```

And then the url call:

```
$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client($this->webhook_url);
$response = $client->post('?' . $this->debugString, [], $this->final_data)->send();

$code = $response->getStatusCode();
```